# Temperature dependence of enthalpy in electrochemistry

Tags: thermodynamics, electrochemistry

I've been trying to use Kirchoff's law to determine the difference in the enthalpies of electrochemical reactions at different temperatures for a general electrochemical process. So here's my progress:

$$\Delta_r G = -nFE_\mathrm{cell}$$ And, $$\mathrm{d}G = V \mathrm{d}P - S \mathrm{d}T$$

Considering the reaction to be occurring at moreover constant pressure, the first term vanishes.

Hence $$\Delta_r S = nF \left(\frac{\partial E_{cell}}{\partial T} \right)_P $$

$$\Delta_r H = - nFE_{cell} + nFT \left(\frac{\partial E_{cell}}{\partial T} \right)_P$$

Since $$ \partial (\Delta_r C_{p,m})= \frac{\partial}{\partial T} (\Delta_r H)$$
I obtained;
$$\Delta_r C_{p,m} = nFT \left( \frac{\partial ^2 E_{cell}}{\partial T^2} \right)_{P}$$

But this seems to imply there is no dependence of $\Delta_r C_{p,m}$ on temperature at all since the Nernst equation implies only linear temperature dependence. So, is there any hidden assumption made during this derivation or is it true that for all electrochemical reactions at constant pressure, specific heat, and hence reaction enthalpy, does not depend on temperature at all?  (I'm a new student to electrochemistry so please pardon me if I made any notational errors)

Comment: Note that the Mathjax \partial is used for partial derivatives. For exact differentials, there is used upright d,  like `$\mathrm{d}G$`  for $\mathrm{d}G$. For nonexact differentials of heat or work, there is used Unicode character "dyet" or as a workaround, \delta as  `$\delta W$` for $\delta W$.

Comment: I will keep that in mind next time onwards, thank you for bringing that to my attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nernst equation implicitly assumes the standard potential (and therefore the general potential too) is function of temperature.

$$\left(\dfrac{\partial^2E^{\circ}_\mathrm{cell}}{\partial T^2}\right)_p \ne 0 \implies \left(\dfrac{\partial^2E_\mathrm{cell}}{\partial T^2}\right)_p \ne 0 \implies \Delta_r C_{p,m} \ne 0$$

The explicit linear dependence of a potential on temperature at the logarithmic term $\dfrac{RT}{nF} \ln{Q}$ describes only potential changes due changing activities of involved compounds. For the given change of activities at constant temperature, the impact on the potential is proportional to absolute temperature.